# How to check if a post has a specific label (using conditional tags)?

Tags: blogger

I'm using blogger, and I want to use different `<title>` tags depending on the post labels. For example, if a post has the label: "SOMELABEL1", it will show `<title>Title1 - Wbsitename</title>`, and if the post has the label: "SOMELABEL2", it will show `<title>2222 - Webitename</title>`.

I have tried to use the following code (which is working on the middle of the page - in the body), but not in the head start:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (l => l.name in "LABEL1")'>
<title>1111 - Webitename</title>.
<b:else/>
<title>2222 - Webitename</title>.
</b:if>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not check `data:post.labels` outside the Blog widget but the good news is that you can use your code inside Blog widget to change the page title via JavaScript.

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "LABEL1")'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.title="1111 - Webitename";
    </script>
<b:else/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.title="2222 - Webitename";
    </script>
</b:if>
```

**But** changing the page title via JavaScript won't help SEO because some web crawlers do not support JavaScript. (Google's does)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does Google crawler support javascript? (I think it is)

Comment: Yes, Google crawlers will follow JS changes to document.title [more info](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

Comment: @Bassam: What do you mean by **Outside Blog Widget**? So what is considered **Inside Blog Widget**?

Comment: I mean inside widget tags like `Outside  <b:widget type='Blog'> inside  </b:widget> Outside `