# How to check if a Blogger Post has specific Label when the Label is HIDDEN?

Tags: blogger

All my Blogger posts have **Labels**, but I choose not to show them on my Blogger Site. On my **Blogger Dashboard -> Posts**, I still can see all my labels for each post and filter them by label, which is what I want. But when I try to check if the current post has a specific label (which it does have), the following code doesn't work (right before `</body>`):

```
<b:section id="testSection" name="Test Section">

        <b:if cond='data:posts any (p => p.labels any (l => l.name == "Label1"))'>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              console.log("Label1");
          </script>
          <link href='post-style-for-label1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        </b:if>

    </b:section>
```

I read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178327/how-to-check-if-a-post-has-a-specific-label-using-conditional-tags), saying that we can't check `data:post.labels` **outside Blog widget**, but when I placed it inside a widget, it says widget cannot contain `<b:if>` -- this is why I placed it under `<b:section>`. But at the end, I still can't make my code to detect **Label1**. I tried the following code but not working too:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Label1")'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Label1");
    </script>
    <link href='post-style-for-label1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</b:if>
```

If I can remember correctly, I have removed the code that displays the labels, but is it necessary to display the labels on the site in order for the code to work? I doubt that because Blogger does have all my labels for every post. How can I make my code to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blogger theme provides several types of widgets like Header, Blog, profile...(26 type) and each type has its data tags. In your example, `data:post.labels` belongs to the widget type **Blog** so, you cannot use it outside widget tags.

Also, a widget can only contain `b:includeable` tags (similar to functions in Javascript)

If your theme already has a blog widget, place your code in the tag `b:includable` with `id='main'` otherwise, create one like the following:

```xml
<b:widget id='Blog1' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main'>

      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>

        <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Label1")'>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             console.log("Label1");
          </script>
        </b:if>

      </b:loop>

    </b:includable>

</b:widget>
```

Comment: `id='Blog1'` already exists, so I created `id='Blog2'` according to your code, but the condition still unable to find my label. As I emphasized in my post, my labels are **HIDDEN**. Could it be the reason why they cannot be found by the `data.post.labels` condition? Or the conditional logic is wrong?

Comment: I just confirmed that `data:post.labels` does not contain any of my post labels, which I did specify some. Any idea what causes this to happen?

Comment: Could it be that, I set my blog template to `b:js='false'`?

Comment: Sorry, to use `post.labels` we need to loop through blog posts. I updated the answer.

Comment: I can't loop through the posts. If you read my question carefully, I want to know if a specific post contains a specific label. Let's say I have a post title **Hello World**, I want to know if this post has a label called **Label1** so that I can apply a `.css` file to all posts with this label. I will update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I just added `<link href='post-style-for-label1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>` to my sample codes so that you'll know clearer the purpose of my question. I want to know if the **current post** has a specific label. Thank you.

Comment: Without data posts you can't get post items and Blog widget will render one post in  loop on single post page not all posts (this is the way it works reverse to home page and index).

Comment: Yup, tested, it works well though, thanks a lot! :)